# Myers’s Lemon Tree

Tags: trees, citrus, lemons

I
Live in Northwest Florida and last winter we got record breaking freezing temperatures. I planted a Myers’s Lemon tree in the fall and even though it was protected it still got some frost damage. It has finally came back with only one branch and there are also small leaves sprouting at the bottom(I have identified them as being Hard Orange leaves)??? Do I trim them off if so will
It effect the tree? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you have suckers from below the graft union (what I interpret your "hard orange leaves at the base" to be) then yes, you want to remove those so that the desired grafted top is what grows.